# How to override 'DefWndProc' in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-messages

I'v code  to override DefWndProc in winform

```
    protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            //Display image
            case MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK:
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                BitmapFormat.WriteBitmap(m_pImageBuffer, m_nWidth, m_nHeight);
                BitmapFormat.GetBitmap(m_pImageBuffer, m_nWidth, m_nHeight, ref ms);
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                this.pictureBox_FingerImg.Image = bmp;
                break;

            default:
                base.DefWndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**'BitmapFormat'** is my model class

However, I can't paste this code in WPF project

how to resolve it?